# How to perform Case Insensitive validation with NJsonSchema for Enums

Tags: c#, enums, json-schema-validator, njsonschema

I am using [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema) to validate a Json against a JsonSchema.

Here is the code snippet. My current code is case-sensitive and validates only RED, and BLUE for enum color.

I want to validate the JObject(JSON) case-insensitively against the Enum Color so that it validates RED, Red, red, BLUE, Blue, blUE, etc. I am retrieving the color enum from a library so I don't have control over it.

Are there any annotations or validation settings that I can use?

```
public class ColorTypes
{
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
    public Color[] Fill { get; set; }
}

// Color is an enum
public enum Color {
    RED,
    BLUE
}

// JsonSchema Creation
JsonSchema ColorSchema = JsonSchema.FromType<ColorTypes>();

// Here is my validation
public ICollection<ValidationError> validateJsonWithSchema(JsonSchema schema, JObject jsonObject)
{
    ICollection<ValidationError> validationResult = schema.Validate(jsonObject);         
    return validationResult;
}
```